# Exception :java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "02/15/2012"

Tags: java, date-format

```
try {
    String str_date=date;
    DateFormat formatter ; 
    Date date1 ; 
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SSSS");
    date1 = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);  
    System.out.println("Today is " +date1 );
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
    System.out.println("Exception :"+e); 
}
```

i got Exception :java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "02/15/2012"

any one help me to solve the issue

Answer (score 4):

You are passing date in this format `02/15/2012`
so you need to do this

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

if you are passing date in this format `02-15-2012`
then you have to do this

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

above will not gives you any error.

Answer (score 3):

remake

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SSSS");
```

to

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

That is the code for you. You are defining the wrong "pattern" in your code. How should the parser parse the date 22/05/2012 if you tell him "Hey the date I will give you has the pattern of yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SSSS" ?

Comment: Thanks I have updated the answer ;-) Im european so I took the false pattern :D

Answer (score 3):

I like more doing it like this:

```
String dateString = "22/11/1982";
DateFormat dF = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
Date date = dF.parse(dateString);
```

Answer (score 1):

The formatting is wrong, even the answers here are wrong.

Your date starts with `MM/dd/yyyy` pattern so change your format to:

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

The reason why it can't be `dd/MM/yyyy` is because you can't have a month of `15` (there's only 12 months in a year).